Derivation of infinite continued fraction
Is this function derivable?
$$y=\cfrac{1}{x+\cfrac{1}{x+\cfrac{1}{x+\cfrac{1}{\ddots}}}}$$
I assumed it is derivable, and wrote it like this
$$y=\cfrac{1}{x+y}$$
$$y^2+xy-1=0$$
$$y=\cfrac{-x\pm\root{}\of{x^2+4}}{2}$$
$$y'=\cfrac{-1\pm\cfrac{x}{\root{}\of{x^2+4}}}{2}$$
If it is derivable, why does it have two derivatives?

Isn't it HaRiBoD?

Take only the positive root

It's obvious that if $x>0$, $y>0$, and so the negative root can be rejected. Thus, for $x>0$,
$$y'=\frac{-1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+4}}}{2}$$
and likewise for $x< 0$,
$$y'=\frac{-1-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+4}}}{2}$$
And $y=1\Rightarrow y'=0$ for $x=0$.
